# ERROR! conflicting action statements (expect, command) in Ansible

Tags: expect, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to install java on several hosts with Ansible.
I looked for some examples of `expect` module to provide answers to the prompts.
I think this syntax is quite fine:

```
- hosts: datanode
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
  tasks:
  - expect:
    name: install java jdk 7
    command: apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
    responses:
    Question:
      'Do you want to continue? [Y/n]': 'Y'
```

But when I try to execute `ansible-playbook file.yml` I receive the error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements (expect, command)

The error appears to have been in '/root/scp.yml': line 5, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
  - expect:
    ^ here
```

Where is the problem?
(I have installed ansible 2.0.1.0, pexpect, python)

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that syntax is "fine" when Ansible is clearly throwing a syntax error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE** that Ansible works with yaml files, and this kind of files are *indented*. This means that the spaces you put before each statement are important to let Ansible to understand how are they nested. [More info about yaml](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html).

Corrected task:

```
- hosts: datanode
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: install java jdk 7
    expect:
      command: apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
      responses:
        Question:
          - 'Y'
          - 'n'
```

This will avoid your syntax error.

Source: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html

Alternatively, if you always want to say "yes" to your `apt-get install` commands, you can add the `-y` argument:

```
apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk
```

Or even better, use the [`apt` Ansible module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html).

Comment: @Héctor Valverde Pareja How would we use expect module with ansible apt module. Could you please give an example.
I get a prompt in the middle of installation and I want to provide 'Y'.
I am using apt module for installing the package.