# Ansible user prompt in apt module - unable to pass value "Yes"

Tags: expect, ansible, apt

I am using ansible apt module [apt](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) in my playbook. It asks for a user prompt and I want to provide "Y". Could some one please tell how this can be done. I used "expect" but it doesn't work.

```
- name: Install latest apparmor packages - xxx-policy
  expect:
    apt: pkg={{ item.name }}={{ item.deb_version }} update_cache=yes state=present force=yes
    with_items: { name: 'xaz-policy', deb_version: '{{ apparmor.xxx_policy.deb_version }}'}
    when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
    responses:
      Question:
        - 'Y'
```

And I get below error

```
TASK [Install latest apparmor packages - xxx-policy] ************************    task path:    /home/jenkins/workspace/OSInnovationB/docker_upgradation_job/playbooks/tasks/test.yml:47 fatal: [xxx-xxx-host-01]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'item' is undefined"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `expect` module as a wrapper around other modules (I assume that is what you are trying to do). The [expect module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html)

> executes a command and responds to prompts The given command will be executed on all selected nodes.

You are getting the `'item' is undefined` error message because the `when` clause has wrong indention. But that wouldn't work anyway. See above.

You can use [playbooks prompts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_prompts.html) in your playbook and that is the only way Ansible will prompt the user for input I'm aware of.

If you just want to make sure that the latest version of a package is installed on a system using apt package manager use this:

```
- name: Install latest apparmor packages - xxx-policy
  apt:
    name: "xaz-policy"
    state: latest
    update_cache: true
```

Comment: I was going through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712453/error-conflicting-action-statements-expect-command-in-ansible and saw a comment "Or even better, use the apt Ansible module.". Was wondering how this can be achieved via apt module itself.

Comment: Stick to the documentation of Ansible. It is really good ... The answer in the question uses `command: apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` if you do that it might work. But now I understand. You are probably looking for `state=latest`. Look at the [module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html). There is no need to do hacky things to install latest version of a package.

Comment: Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** usr.bin.docker (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?

Comment: I don't want the default option.  Which means I have to pass "Yes" . And question is not related to latest version. Its regarding overwriting a file

Comment: I added that to my answer